# Elasticsearch: Sort Aggregation Alphabetically by non-key field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

What I'm trying to do is aggregate around a **nameId** field and sort the buckets by the name field. I'm able to sort by age.

I've figured out a work around to sort by the other fields of the document but it is limited to the numeric fields.

Example of my query where I am able to order by the numeric fields is below.

If I change the sums aggregation in **a2** to a terms aggregation and aggregate it on a non numeric field (such as name), then it results in an error from elastic search:
:"*Invalid terms aggregation order path [a2]. Terms buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end."*"

Is there a way to sort the buckets on a non-numeric field?

```
{
 "size" : 0,       
 "aggs": {
    "a1": {
      "terms": { 
        "field": "nameId",
        "size":5
        ,"order": {"a2": "desc"}
      },
      "aggs":{
        "a2":{
          "sum":{
            "size": 0,
            "field":"age"
          }
        },
        "aggs":{
           "top_hits":{
             "size":1,
                "_source": {
                "include":["name", "nameId", "age"]}
           }

       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**NOTE:**
I'm asking this question in the context of just the aggregation alone. Obviously what I want done in this question can be done by the normal query but for other factors/reason I need to do this in the aggregation.

I'm just simplifying the query/skipping the reasons this needs to be done in the aggregation as they're not important in the context of this question.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I wish you the best of luck though